# How to access innerHTML but ignore <script> tags

Tags: javascript, html

I have a plugin that looks through the HTML and replaces text. However, with my current implementation text in script tags are getting caught in the search as well. This leads to broken scripts on the affected pages.

```
var pageText = document.body.innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = pageText.replace(regextgoeshere);
```

I tried my best to filter it out through my regex pattern but I need to figure out how to skip all  tags.

Is there a way to skip all  tags when getting innerHTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe your best option is to use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) and negate undesired elements. Then replace the textContent instead innerHTML. By using innerHTML you risk breaking document tags.

This is a cross-browser solution.

```
var matches = document.querySelectorAll("*:not(html):not(head):not(script):not(meta):not(link)");
console.log(matches);
[].forEach.call(matches, function(elem) {
  var text = ('innerText' in elem) ? 'innerText' : 'textContent';
  elem[text] = elem[text].replace("this", "works");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m6qhuesv/

Note 1: HTML, HEAD, META and LINK tags disallow modify textContext.

Note 2: innerText is a proprietary IE thing (also works in chrome). The W3C defines [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.textContent) as the official property.

Comment: Thank you for such an excellent response. This will work great because it will be a chrome plugin.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I misunderstood your requirements

If you want something more sophisticated, try Douglas Crockford's [walking the DOM](http://www.javascriptcookbook.com/article/Traversing-DOM-subtrees-with-a-recursive-walk-the-DOM-function) function:

```
function walkTheDOM(node, func) {
    func(node);
    node = node.firstChild;
    while (node) {
        walkTheDOM(node, func);
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
}
```

You can use the `tagName` property of `node` to skip `<script>` elements:

```
if(node.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'script'){
    node.innerText = node.innerText.replace(regextgoeshere);
}
```

Comment: Protip: innerText will not render HTML entities: http://jsfiddle.net/btipling/b21hxpuj/ Have fun with that.

Comment: @BjornTipling: `.innerText` non-standard and Firefox doesn't support it.

Comment: It doesn't matter, no kind of dynamically generated text node will render HTML entities. http://jsfiddle.net/btipling/b21hxpuj/1/ You have to use a boatload of JavaScript to fix this.

Comment: @BjornTipling It still does in my second code snippet. the textContent property could also be used, or `nodeType` could be used to test before performing the replace, but I'm not sure what the OP's exact requirements are here.  Thanks for your input!

Comment: Yeah I don't really understand what's going on in this question, I just know use of innerText or text nodes is problem fraught and best avoided unless you are adding pure text in a limited capacity.

Answer (score 1):

I think we tend to think elements and miss nodes!
However this problem is best solved by thinking nodes.

Australian Alex has best solution
http://blog.alexanderdickson.com/javascript-replacing-text

```
function myRecursiveSearch(node,.....) {

   var excludeElements = ['script', 'style', 'iframe', 'canvas'];

   var child = node.firstChild;

   if(child==null)
     return;

    do {
        switch (child.nodeType) {

        case 1:
            if (excludeElements.indexOf(child.tagName.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
                continue;
            }

            myRecursiveSearch(child,.....);
            break;

        case 3:
           child.nodeValue=doReolace(child.nodeValue,.....);
           break;

        }

    } while (child = child.nextSibling);

}


function doTranslit(strtext,....) {
   .....
   return strtext;
}
```

Comment: *Australian Alex* hehe

Answer (score -1):

Didn't check but you can try.

```
var pageText = document.body.innerHTML;
mypagewithoutScriptTag = pageText.replace(<script>(.*?)</script>);
```